# check if record exists using prisma graphql apollo

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, prisma

trying to check if a record exists in a table in Postgres using Prisma, but seems like I can only query the id field, but not any other fields like `name` and `location`, which gives a compiler error

model `schema.prisma`

```
model place {
  id             Int              @id @default(dbgenerated("nextval('place_id_seq'::regclass)"))
  name           String
  location       String @unique
}
```

generated type

```
export type Place = {
  __typename?: 'Place';
  name?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  location?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;

};
```

Query resolver

```
let findPlace = await prisma.place.findUnique(
        {
          where: {
            name: "abc"
          }
        }
)
```

error

```
Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'placeWhereUniqueInput'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type 'placeWhereUniqueInput'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1361, 5): The expected type comes from property 'where' which is declared here on type '{ select?: placeSelect | null | undefined; include?: placeInclude | null | undefined; rejectOnNotFound?: RejectOnNotFound | undefined; where: placeWhereUniqueInput; }'
```

what's missing here to make this work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Prisma won't accept `findUnique` queries where the condition only contains non unique fields (in this case, name). If you just need to find whether a place record with appropriate condition exists or not, you can use the [`count` API](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/aggregation-grouping-summarizing#filtered-count).

```js
let placeCount = await prisma.place.count(
        {
          where: {
            name: "abc"
          }
        }
)
// placeCount == 0 implies does not exist
```

Comment: This is best because transmit less data.

Answer (score 7):

`findUnique` only works for unique fields. You shouldn't use `count` either as it unnecessarily goes through the whole table.

The better approach is to use `findFirst`, which is basically a `LIMIT 1` on the database, so the database can stop searching for more results after the first hit.

```js
const exists = !!await prisma.place.findFirst(
  {
    where: {
      name: "abc"
    }
  }
);
```

I'm using the `!!` to cast the object to a boolean.

Comment: I liked the `!!` cast